# Can anybody recommend a wireless PCI card working out-of-the-box in Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit)?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, pci

I have recently bought new desktop. Everything works flawlessly in Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, except my (kinda outdated) wireless PCI card Realtek 8185. So I am about to buy new one.

Please can you recommend a PCI card (or at least chipset), that is known to work in new Ubuntu without glitches (no need to wrap Windows, drivers etc...). The information I have found on the web seems to be far too inconsistent, so I would like to hear some experiences.

Comment: This is very close (or even on) the edge of the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) stating: "This is not the right place for: Shopping Recommendations"

Answer (score 1):

I would heartily recommend the EDIMAX n300 EW-7722In Wireless 802.11b/g/n 32-bit PCI Adaptor. ***NOT*** low profile & Windows did not suspend & reconnect properly, but the driver is now in the kernel & it worked flawlessly with Ubuntu/Linux. I sold mine on eBay as needed to dual boot with Windows.

I now use a Realtek RTL8188CU Based Chip ~ USB Wireless NIC (Edimax EW-7811Un USB wireless/Solwise NET-WL-UMD-606N) as need to dual boot. However driver needs compiling with every kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Intel Wireless cards are known to work very well in Linux. Unfortunately, not many plain PCI products have been developed and their main focus is on the mobile/notebook market. As far as I can see, only one is still available:

- The [Intel PRO/Wireless 5000 WLAN PCI adapter](http://download.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/pro5000/pro5000_info.pdf)

Also refer to these community maintained pages:

- [Ubuntu Help: WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)
- [Wikipedia: Comparison of open-source wireless drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_wireless_drivers)
- related question: [Wireless network adapter manufacturers with best Linux compatibility record?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173677/wireless-network-adapter-manufacturers-with-best-linux-compatibility-record)